# Inapproximability result for a special version of 1-in-kSAT

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability

Max 1-in-kSAT is the following maximisation problem :

Given $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and $m$ clauses $C_1, \dots, C_m$, find a valuation such that the number of clauses satisfied by **exactly** one literal is maximal.

In the following paper, there are several inaproximability results about this problem, such as

**Theorem 9** : if $ZPP\neq NP$, then for every $\epsilon$, there is a constant $c$ such that there
is no polynomial time $(n^{1-\epsilon})$-approximation algorithm for Max 1-in-$(c\log n)$SAT

https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/pubs/gt05.pdf

I want to know if this result is still true if we suppose that $m=O(n^{\delta})$ where $\delta$ is any positive constant

Any ideas, remarks, or paper would be useful :)